# Looking for a diff gem for differences between two ruby object instances

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rails-activerecord

So if I had two car object instances that looked something like:

```
car1 = {make: Ford, model: Taurus, color: purple}
car2 = {make: Ford, model: f150, color: purple}
```

I'd get something like:

```
car1.method(car2)
>> model:f150
```

Any ideas?  I would really like to find specific differences in string elements of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work specifically with Ruby hashes, as in your example, this will work:

```
class Hash
  def diff (other)
    result = {}

    self.keys.each do |key|
      if self[key] != other[key]
        result[key] = other[key]
      end
    end

    return result
  end
end

car1 = {make: "Ford", model: "Taurus", color: "purple"}
car2 = {make: "Ford", model: "f150", color: "purple"}

car1.diff(car2)
# => {:model=>"f150"}
```

If, on the other hand, you want to work with objects other than hashes, you should post code showing an example of what you're looking for.